# Como separar "palavras" em CamelCase no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, camel-case

Como eu posso separar "palavras" em **CamelCase** utilizando hífen por exemplo?

Com uma string:

```
string example = "CamelCase";
// CamelCase para:
// Camel-Case
```

e enumerador:

```
enum Example {
    CamelCase
}

Example.CamelCase.ToString();
// CamelCase para:
// Camel-Case
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Opção mais performática, flexível, integrada e mais correta segundo o critério que se já tem um separador não deve colocar outro:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("CamelCase".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("Camel-Case".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("Camel---Case".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("Camel.Case".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("Ca".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("aC".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("CC".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("C".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("CamelCaseC".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("pascalCase".SplitCamelCase());
        WriteLine("CamelCase".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("Camel-Case".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("Camel---Case".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("Camel.Case".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("Ca".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("aC".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("CC".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("C".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("CamelCaseC".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
        WriteLine("pascalCase".SplitCamelCase('-', ""));
    }
    public static string SplitCamelCase(this string text, char separator = '-', string separators = "-=_+!@#$%&*()'^~[]{}/?;:.,<>|\\\"") {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.Length < 2) return text;
        var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length + text.Length / 3);
        for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
            if (char.IsUpper(text[i]) && i > 0 && !separators.Contains(text[i - 1].ToString())) sb.Append(separator);
            sb.Append(text[i]);
            
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bLgwLO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kSuqXa). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitCamelCase.cs).

Não importa se a origem da *string* vem de um `enum`, você faz no texto, não faz no `enum`. E pegar a *string* do `enum` já demonstrou saber fazer.

Comment: Kkkkk, adorei o uso de extensão, exatamente o que eu queria. Eu tinha um pouco de dificuldade com extensões, mas depois desse exemplo, consegui compreender o uso, bela resposta. Só não entendi o que o `string separators` faz, no caso ele verifica se o caractere anterior é algum dos separadores? E se for não adiciona de novo?

Comment: Exatamente isso, claro que é opcional como mostrei, e pode dizer quais caracteres serão considerados separadores para não repetir. Não sei se todas opções resultam no que queria, mas aí é só adaptar o critério. Por exemplo, "CC" pode ser que prefira não ter separador

Answer (score 15):

Fiz com base [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781533/5429980), ela não usa expressão regular veja:

```
string camelCase = string.Concat(ExampleEnum.CamelCase.ToString().Select((x,i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "-" + x.ToString() : x.ToString()));
```

Saída:

> Camel-Case

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sTSTPp).

Comment: Também gostei da resposta. E as vezes eu sou tentado a comandos de apenas uma linha kkkk, aceitei a do @Maniero porque ele utilizou extensões e também tem a questão da flexibilidade, achei que me serviu melhor, além do "mais performático", mesmo que micro kkkkk que me chama atenção também kkkkk =P. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela resposta :D

Answer (score 9):

Fiz o seguinte código, não é tão simples como o do @gato, mas pode ser mais didático. Espero que ajude:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string camelCase = "CamelCase";
    string newCamelCase= HiffenCamelCase(camelCase);
         
    
    Console.WriteLine(camelCase);
    Console.WriteLine(newCamelCase);
    
}

static string HiffenCamelCase(string s)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        string result = s[0].ToString();
        for (int i = 1; i < s.Length;i++)
        {
            result += s[i]+ (i+1<s.Length ? (Char.IsUpper(s[i+1]) ?"-" : "") : "");
        }
    
        return result;
    }
    else return s;
}
```

**Saída:**

> CamelCase
>
> Camel-Case

Coloquei no .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kpGVQE

Answer (score 8):

Usando expressões regulares podemos por exemplo:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
id = Regex.Replace(id,"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])","-");
```

Um exemplo completo podia ser:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    WriteLine("CamelCase".SplitCamelCase());  }
  public static string SplitCamelCase(this string id){
    return Regex.Replace(id,"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])","-"); }
}
```

Naturalmente, adapta as expressões à semântica pretendida. Por exemplo
se pretendermos que sequências de maiusculas sejam separadas, `..."(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])"...`

Answer (score 3):

Pode ser assim também:

```
string camelCaseString = "EuSouUmaStringCamelCase";
string retorno = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
    camelCaseString,
    "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])",
    "-$1",
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();

Console.Write(retorno);
```