# Como escrever siglas em camelCase?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome, camel-case

Como eu devo tratar as siglas no `camelCase`? eu devo deixá-las totalmente maiúsculas ou só a primeira letra? Como ficaria a variável `algumaCoisaSiglaAleatoria`? Ou `algumaCoisaSIGLAAleatoria`?

Comment: Seja bem vindo Hugo, isto te ajudaria? [Como separar “palavras” em CamelCase no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278619/como-separar-palavras-em-camelcase-no-c)  Ou isto: [Como funciona o CamelCase? Onde uso maiúsculas e minúsculas em nomes? [duplicada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239964/como-funciona-o-camelcase-onde-uso-mai%C3%BAsculas-e-min%C3%BAsculas-em-nomes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isto tem um pouco a ver com gosto, e o que eu digo sempre, não importa como faça seja consistente. Consistência tem a ver com o time que você trabalha, e tem a ver com a cultura da tecnologia usada, por isso deveria procurar essa informação para tomar uma decisão. Eu sei que algumas tecnologias não têm isso documentado, e até são inconsistentes, já vi muita inconsistência no uso.

De forma geral eu acho muito feio algo tudo maiúsculo e acho até que estraga o propósito do *camel/PascalCase*, então eu iria pelo caminho de `CalcularIcms()`. Pensando o mesmo um, `CalcularIr()` pode ficar feio também, então a solução dada pela Microsoft, conforme resposta do Germano, pode fazer sentido e ficar melhor `CalcularIR()`, mas não tenho tanta certeza porque apesar de ser uma regra fica um pouco inconsistente. Essa decisão em específico parece ser uma dessas coisas que precisa usar e ver como fica.

Eu [já respondi como deveria ser em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101), é a cultura estabelecida nessa tecnologia, então deveria seguir, porque acaba sendo consistente com ela, apesar de ter uma exceção explicitada, mas tem que achar a cultura da sua tecnologia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/141e06ef(v=vs.71)) da Microsoft e seguindo o seu exemplo o correto seria `algumaCoisaSiglaAleatoria` porque a sigla tem um tamanho maior que dois caracteres. Quando a sigla tiver dois caracteres ou um, o correto seria em letras maiúsculas: `systemIO`.